# AngularJS Data Binding with Getter and Setter Service Method

Tags: angularjs, service

I'm struggling to understand how data binding and Service works togheter in AngularJS.
I've 1 controller and 1 service.

My service:

```
myAppServices.factory('SharedData',['$http',function($http){

    var _data = {
        "first_prop" :{
            "name": "first_prop",
            "info": "infofirst_prop"
        },
        "second_prop" :{
            "name": "second_prop",
            "info": "infosecond_prop"
        }

    };

    return {
        getProp:  function (name) {               
            return _data[name];
        },
        setProp: function (name,value) {
            _data[name] = value;
        }
    };

}])
```

My controller code:

```
webAppControllers.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','SharedData',
    function ($scope, $http,SharedData) {

        $scope.data = angular.copy(SharedData.getProp("first_prop"))

        $scope.print = function()
        {
            console.log(SharedData.getProp("first_prop"));
        }

        $scope.modify = function()
        {
            SharedData.setProp("first_prop",$scope.data)
        }


    }
]);
```

And this is my view:

```
<form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Modify the name...">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="info">Info</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="data.info" class="form-control" id="info" placeholder="Modify the info ...">
                </div>

                <button ng-click="modify()" class="btn btn-default">Modify</button>
                <button ng-click="print()" class="btn btn-default">Print</button>
            </form>
```

If i modify the view, overriding value in the form, and then i click on print button, console.log return me values store in services(into private variable _data), and this is what i excpected.

Then if i click on modify button, and again print button, this time cosole.log shows me modified values that was saved on private var _data in my service. Also this behavior is expected.

The strange thing appear when after i did this interaction with my webapp, i again modify value in the form and click on print button without clicking on modify button. Values stored in service are modified even if i never click modify button and so i never call SharedData.setProp() method.

With the method angular.copy(), i expected to create new variable(a new copy of a variable), and so if i modify this "$scoped" variable i expected it was impossible modify directly private _data variable in my service.

Why this happens? Are there a method to modify and access private variable in service only by some defined method?

Thanks in advance.

Best regard,
Alessandro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click setProp, the object in SharedData and in the scope is the same object.

To solve this, call this line again after you call "modify()":

```
$scope.modify = function()
{
   SharedData.setProp("first_prop",$scope.data)
   // grab another copy of the first_prop object, or else its the same reference.
   $scope.data = angular.copy(SharedData.getProp("first_prop"));
}
```

There are other ways to solve this, such as in setProp, pass `angular.copy($scope.data)`, etc.

Always be aware that when you pass objects in javascript, the pass by reference, not by value.